# How do you insert data into a foreign key in a table which is already filled using postman for a spring boot project

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, postman, mapping

I'm new to Spring boot and need help with One to Many mapping. I have two tables called Course and Instructor. One instructor has many courses and one course has only one instructor. The course table has four records filled but the instructor_id(foreign key of instructor) is empty. I know how to enter data into a foreign key while filling in the rest of the table like this,

```
{
"instructor" : {
    "firstName" : "Dave",
    "lastName" : "John",
    "telephone" : 714523698,
    "courses" : [
        {
            "courseNo" : 1011,
            "courseName" :"Network Engineering",
            "duration" : "2 years"

        },
        {
            "courseNo" : 1012,
            "courseName" :"Internet of Things",
            "duration" : "3 years"

        }
    ]
}
```

But what I need is a way to enter the instructor_id to the correct course by only inputting the courseNo.
The controller for the above process,

```
public class TeachController {

@Autowired
private InstructorRepository instructorRepository;

@Autowired
private CourseRepository courseRepository;

@GetMapping("/findTeachCourse")
public List<Instructor> findTeachCourse(){
    return instructorRepository.findAll();
}

@PostMapping("/newTeachCourse")
public Instructor newTeachCourse(@RequestBody TeachRequest teachRequest){
    return instructorRepository.save(teachRequest.getInstructor());
}}
```

[Course table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXTmE.png)

Hope this information is enough to help me out. ^^'

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@ManyToOne` annotation to map the instructor_id column in the Course table to the Instructor table.

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="instructor_id")
    private Instructor instructor;
```

Then, in your controller, you can use the InstructorRepository to find the instructor by their id and set the instructor property of the Course object.

```
    Instructor instructor = instructorRepository.findById(teachRequest.getInstructorId());
    course.setInstructor(instructor);
```